# First time using an IDE...not sure what this means?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So all of this code works fine in CodePen, but I'm trying to get used to using an IDE instead. I've figured out how to link a CSS file to an HTML file, and I think it works the same way with a JS file. However, perhaps the CodePen IDE is a bit more...lenient on the syntax? Something isn't working right in Webstorm, and I'm not sure what it is.

In my code, the IDE tells me one of the methods (I think?) are deprecated? What would I use instead of this? Also, if you know off the top of your head on why some of my jquery selectors are highlighted, it would be appreciated. And also the green squiggly lines (although I'm pretty sure it means 'typo', but I don't know why it thinks it's a typo, because it's part of a URL?)

Lastly, I'm doing this stuff at work, so the files are saved locally...what would be the easiest way to get these files to the computer at my house? Is there some kind of feature on webstorm that allows you to do this, or do just have to go through Google drive, dropbox, etc...?

Thanks in advance!

[image: HTML file]

[image: JS file]

[image: CSS file]

Comment: You didn't load jQuery (should be loaded before your script).

Comment: To explain the ready deprecation notice:[Starting jQuery 3.0 the only non-deprecated syntax for the `.ready()` is `$( handler )`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) like `$(()=>{console.log('Im ready')})`

Comment: I loaded the script up in the <head> element in the HTML file at the top; is there a reason you say the bottom? @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @PhillipChoi That was a mistake of mine. The real problem is that you didn't load jQuery (which codePen does it for you by just checking it from a menu).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Actually I think I did that part as well...I went into settings and downloaded and installed jQuery. Do I need to add a line of code to my JS file? Or does Webstorm automatically load jQuery in the background?

Comment: No you have to do it your self. `<script src="path/to/jquery/file"></script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the error because you didn't load jQuery. Make sure to include it in your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

The green squiggles under `.quotations` indicate that, while syntactically correct, you are writing unnecessary lines of code. `border-color: green` and `border-style: solid` can be re-written as `border: auto solid green`.

The squiggles under the URLs can be safely ignored -- they're simply not recognised as valid syntax by the IDE.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Do I need to add that line of code in my <head> if I already went into the settings > Javascript > Libraries > and downloaded and installed the jQuery Library? I assumed that after I did that, jQuery would just sort of 'run' in the background of all my files?

Comment: No that won't add the javascript to each HTML page... that is only for reference while editing in the IDE...

Comment: You still need to **reference** the jQuery library. If you've downloaded it, you need to reference it with a relative path such as `<script src="[PATH]/jQuery.min.js"></script>`. Otherwise it won't be included, and you'll see in your F12 debugger than `$` is undefined.